# Ruby on Rails: Too many open files error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file

Can any one help with this error - **26401#0: accept() failed (24: Too many open files)**
related to nginx

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you have more open connections than your system limits allows?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you close all the files/sockets/... when you don't need them anymore.